# como ir de un Fragment a un Actvity

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Lo que intento es que al hacer click en un item del `ListView` que esta en un `fragment` me lleve a un `Activity`.

```
       @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        listaconimagenes adapter;

        frutas = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arraycincofrutas);
        lista = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lista_frutas);
        adapter = new listaconimagenes(getActivity(), frutas, imagenes);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(R.id.main_content, Main3Activity.class);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que  estas realizando es incorrecto:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(R.id.main_content, Main3Activity.class);
```

**necesitas como primer parámetro para el intent, el contexto**, y como segundo parámetro la `Activity` que deseas iniciar.

En el caso de un `Fragment`, puedes obtener el contexto de la `Activity` mediante `getActivity()`. Para iniciar la Activity debes usar el método [**startActivity()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) :

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Main3Activity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

---

Revisa la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Este sería tu código, el cual inicia una nueva `Activity` al dar click en el primer elemento del `ListView` (primer elemento es posicion 0):

```
 lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Main3Activity.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Vas muy bien, solo te falta iniciar la actividad después del intent.

```
startActivity(intent);
```